# Get data from multiple collections in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I have two collections, namely Orders and Employee. I first find all orders from Orders collection of a certain customer using the customer id and then need to use a field from the result to find data from Employee collection. The problem I am facing is result that I get from Orders is an array so I need to iterate through it using a for loop and then inside the for loop find the Employee data. The first part of orders works but the second doesn't it always me a 0 array value.

```
        async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            Order.find({ user_id: req.body.id}, {sort: { id: -1 }}, function(err, order) {
                callback(null, order);
            });
        },
        function(order, callback) {
            for(var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
                Employee.find({id: order[i].id}, 'field', function(err, employee) {
                    if (employee.length > 0) {
                        order[i].field = employee[i].field;
                    }
                    order[i].id = order[i].otherid;
                    regs.push(order[i]);
                });
            callback(null, regs);
            }
        }], function (err, result) {
            res.send(result);
        });
```

But the result is this: [0], which is not the expected result. What am I doing wrong here?
Any other solutions??

Answer (score 0):

You can try $lookup in mongodb . i think help to you

i have order collection  like this

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc", "price" : 12, "quantity" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "jkl", "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 3  }
```

and another collection  is inventory like this

```
{ "_id" : 1, "sku" : "abc", description: "product 1", "instock" : 120 }
{ "_id" : 2, "sku" : "def", description: "product 2", "instock" : 80 }
{ "_id" : 3, "sku" : "ijk", description: "product 3", "instock" : 60 }
{ "_id" : 4, "sku" : "jkl", description: "product 4", "instock" : 70 }
{ "_id" : 5, "sku": null, description: "Incomplete" }
{ "_id" : 6 }
```

am using aggregate to find all the order data and then i need to find the inventory data using field of order collection

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "inventory", //another collection name
          localField: "item", // order collection field
          foreignField: "sku", // inventory collection field
          as: "inventory_docs"
        }
   }
])
```

output

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
   "item" : "abc",
  "price" : 12,
  "quantity" : 2,
  "inventory_docs" : [
    { "_id" : 1, "sku" : "abc", description: "product 1", "instock" : 120 }
  ]
}
{
  "_id" : 2,
  "item" : "jkl",
  "price" : 20,
  "quantity" : 1,
  "inventory_docs" : [
    { "_id" : 4, "sku" : "jkl", "description" : "product 4", "instock" : 70 }
  ]
}
{
  "_id" : 3,
  "inventory_docs" : [
    { "_id" : 5, "sku" : null, "description" : "Incomplete" },
    { "_id" : 6 }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Any thing in Mongoose?

Comment: Like I said I am using a for loop and just need one field from the Employee collection so do you think aggregate and $lookup is the right way to go? And moreover I have added an Id field myself so I don't work with the default Id's offered by MongoDb

Comment: ya it right . $lookup is avoid the for loop and it available in mongodb 3.2 olny . it latest command in mongodb .. $lookup only the way to find the data in another collection

Comment: Can you help me in Implementing this is Mongoose? How do I go about it?

Comment: Hey not really going anywhere with this!

Comment: Showing your schemas would help a bit; the JSON you're showing doesn't match what you're indicating in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `populate()` in this case.  It's a little tricky to be sure, since you didn't publish your current schemas here, but let's assume for a moment that you have a setup like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var orderSchema = new Schema({
    user : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }, 
    employee : {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Employee' }
   /* Other things */ 
}); 
mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

Now, given that setup, you can query like so:

```
Order.find({user: new ObjectId(req.body.id)}).sort({id:-1}).populate('employee').exec(function(e, orders){
  /*  whatever  you want to do with the orders, each of which will have the employee data filled in by here */
});
```

If you want to pull only some fields from the Employee model, you can do so like `.populate('employee','name')`.  Full documentation is on the [mongoose site](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)